# Jekyll posts with HTML

Tags: html, css, jekyll

Can someone offer some guidance or advice on how to handle structuring my portfolio pages using Jekyll. My posts handle the bulk of the work with a mix of variables and post content. I'm having an issue rendering the post pages as the HTML and markdown markup are getting janky together.

Essentially, I'd like to use variables to automate the pulling of content & info across pages. Ie homepage features title, id, home-image and individual portfolio pages are driven by everything between {{ content }}. When i try to address layout within posts, this is where things fall apart. As you can see by the intended HTML with CSS selectors, I'm trying to do a 'unique' layout, that is less blog like (content & images running down the page) and instead, use Neat&Bourbon to handle my image blocks and caption blocks.

Is there an efficent way to do this?

```
        ---
    category: Pitch
    featured: false
    publish: true
    layout: project
    type: website redesign

    id: "basil-haydens"

    role: "art direction, design"
    client: "Basil Hayden's"
    title: "Basil Hayden's"
    description: "A site built for true whiskey connoisseurs"

    summary: "Basil Hayden's, Whiskey. Among other things is a site geared toward true whiskey afficianados. With content curated by Max Wastler, the site features lifestyle content paired with recipes and traditional liquor site content making it a unique destination for whiskey connoissers."

    homeimage: hero.png
    images:
        - img-2.jpg
        - img-3.jpg
    backgroundColor: "RGB(226, 122, 15)" 
    accentColor: "#333"
    ---
    <section class="content">
    <div class="aside">
    ###### Credit
    - Designed at UnitOneNine.
    - Art Direction *Design–Amit Patel*
    - Walton Issacson
    </div>
    <div class="overview">
    <h6> Project Overview </h6>
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content--images-three">
    <h6>Homepage</h6>
    <div class="span-6-12">
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/intro-1.jpg)
    </div>
    <div class="span-3-12">
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/intro-2.jpg)
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/intro-3.jpg)
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content--images-six">
    ######Final Designs
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/1.jpg)
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/2.jpg)
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/3.jpg)
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/4.jpg)
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/5.jpg)
    </section>
    <section class="content--images-three">
    <div class="span-6-12">
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/intro-1.jpg)
    </div>
    <div class="span-3-12">
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/intro-2.jpg)
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/intro-3.jpg)
    </div>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div class="span-8-12">
    ![My helpful screenshot](/images/{{ page.id }}/cocktail-club.jpg)
    </div>
    ###### Old Fashioneds before they were cool
    The crux of any liquor site, the recipes. Since curation was key, a basic recipe layout and design was used to account for varying assets and editability in Expression Engine.
    </section>
```

Comment: Can someone inform me why my question is -1? I'm trying to improve my questions for the future but StackExchange documentation provides little help on how to correct responses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand you question, but I believe your problem is to have markdown rendered in html.

In your _config.yml file, set :

```
markdown: kramdown

kramdown:
  parse_block_html: true
  parse_span_html: true
```

Answer (score 1):

David Jacquel's answer ultimately led me to the right answer however it is not complete. I switched my library from Markdown to Kramdown and set flags for parsing html, etc as true.

Next, Kramdown supports a shortcut for adding 'classes' to block elements:

```
> A nice blockquote
{: .class1 .class2}
```

**Which renders to**:

```
<blockquote class="class1 class2">
  <p>A nice blockquote</p>
</blockquote>
```

In the end, i modified my jekyll markup to use section id's, parseable by kramdown into HTML and traditional markdown markup with css classes passed as kramdown shortcuts*.

I also streamlined my layout with less sections and less HTML/CSS markup.

The result...it works however someone could argue it's not as clean as HTML markup. This is true but the added paragraph tags wrapping front-matter content is an issue with jekyll nonetheless.

[*]http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is outdated because Jekyll now supports `kramdown`, the parameters in the `_config.yml` file are not necessary. If you need to add a class to your post while you're writing markdown, you just use the following syntax...

```
> You want this to render as a blockquote in your html. But right now you are writing your post in markdown.
{: .your-class }
```

This should render your blockquote with the class that you specified bellow.